# Php equivalent for gcloud auth print-identity-token

Tags: php, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

My goal is to trigger a google cloud function through my php code. For that I need an identity token as the Bearer, but my server does not have gcloud installed on it.
I have a working service-account and I created an object through the Google_Client ("google/apiclient": "2.10.1"):

```
$this->setAuthConfig($serviceJson);
$scope = [Google_Service_Compute::CLOUD_PLATFORM, 'openid', 'email'];
$this->addScope($scope);
if ($this->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
  $this->fetchAccessTokenWithAssertion();
}
$this->getAccessToken()
```

Using this client I can fetch only the access_token (which is unauthorized to trigger a cloud function) but the id_token is always empty.

How can I get the id_token? Is there a php library that can help or do I need to do a separate POST request(s) to get the id_token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I found is like this:

1. Generate a [JWT manually](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating) (from the data that is in the service account)
2. send it to https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token and receive a token
3. use the token in the CF call

Comment: The inimitable @john-hanley wrote about using Application Default Credentials (ADC) with PHP. His article includes acquiring identity tokens. https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-application-default-credentials-php/ or you may read Google.Auth directly: https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-php#call-using-an-id-token